# Obtener objeto del arraylist.Java

Tags: java

tengo este método para obtener el mayor.

```
public static void met(ArrayList lista) {
        int aux = 0;
        int a;
        for(int i = 0; i<lista.size();i++) {
            a = (int) lista.get(i);
            if(a>aux) {             
                aux = a;//obtener el maximo de una lista
            }
        }
        System.out.print(aux);
    }
```

Y quiero hacer lo mismo pero ahora con objetos:

Pero no sé como hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

Del mismo modo que tienes una variable `int` para almacenar el máximo y luego ir comparando, puedes declarar un objeto para almacenar la referencia al objeto que cumplió la condición.

```
public static void metodoVoraz(ArrayList<Objeto> becas) {
    ArrayList<Objeto> nuevaLista = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
    int aux = 0;
    Objeto obj;

    for(int i = 0; i < becas.size(); i++) {
        Objeto tmp = (Objeto) becas.get(i);
        int a = obj.getDiferencia();

        if(a > aux) {
            aux = a;
            obj = tmp;
        }
    }

    // Aquí, el objeto obj es el máximo
}
```

Por cierto, ahora se hace el `get(i)` de la lista por parámetro, no del objeto que declarabas sin instanciar.

**Posible solución alternativa**
Puedes ordenar la lista por ese valor de mayor a menor y devolver el primer objeto de la lista.

```
public static Objeto getMax(ArrayList<Objeto> list) {

    if (list.size() == 0) return null;

    Collections.sort(list, new ObjetoComparator());
    return list.get(0);
}
```

La clase `ObjetoComparator` implementa la interfaz `Comparator<T>` de tipo `Objeto` y sirve para comparar dos objetos de tipo `Objeto`, en nuestro caso.

```
class ObjetoComparator implements Comparator<Objeto> {
    public int compare(Objeto a, Objeto b) 
    { 
        return b.getDiferencia() - a.getDiferencia(); 
    } 
}
```

Compara según el valor de retorno del método `#getDiferencia` y, en este caso, ordena de mayor a menor.

> También se podría hacer que `Object` implementara la interfaz `Comparable<T>`, siempre y cuando querramos siempre ordenar del mismo modo. A la hora de llamar `Collections.sort(list)` no necesitaríamos pasar ningún otro argumento, ya que internamente se llamará al método `#compareTo` de la clase `Objeto` que implementa de la interfaz `Comparable<T>`.

Más información [aquí](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-sort-java-examples/).

**Edit**
El mismo ejemplo del sorting se puede implementar con lambdas, como apunta @MrDave1999.
Aquí va el ejemplo

```
public static Objeto getMax(ArrayList<Objeto> list) {

    if (list.size() == 0) return null;

    Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Objeto::getDiferencia)
                                     .reversed());
    return list.get(0);
}
```

Crea un `Comparator` anónimo que apunta al método `#getDiferencia` de la clase `Objeto`. Como por defecto, los `Comparator` numéricos son ascendentes, se llama al método `#reversed` para invertir el orden del sorting.

Usar lambdas es una buena manera de tener un código más modular y limpio.
Hay que tener en cuenta, por otra parte, que las lambdas sirven procisamente para crear funciones y clases anónimas, por lo que no son reutilizables.

Comment: A partir de Java 8, se puede usar lambdas. Por lo tanto, el código quedaría así: `Collections.sort(list, (a, b) -> b.getDiferencia() - a.getDiferencia());` . De este modo no se necesita crear una clase personalizada o anónima.

Comment: No quería complicarlo demasiado. Creo que usando una clase se ve bastante bien. Pero bueno, voy a hacer el edit para ilustrarlo.